# Message framework: Add message when saving Page class in Wagtail

Tags: django, wagtail

So I would like to check if a certain field has changed and if so, display a info-message to the user that they should review other datapoints. I feel that the Django messages framework should be ideal for this, but I cant find where to hook in to the wagtail Page class to get this to work.

Right now I have the check on the save method for the page like below, but I do not have access to the request object here, so I cant use massage.add_message (since this uses the request object as a parameter).

What am I missing?

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    if self.pk is not None:
        original = EventDetail.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
        if (
            original.start_date != self.start_date
            and self.messages.all().count() > 0
        ):
            messages.add_message(
                request,
                messages.INFO,
                _(
                    "You have just changed starting time on an event that contains messages, please review the times for the message sends."
                ),
            )
```

**Edit** after the reply by **@gasman**, my new before_edit hook now looks like this, can this be done in a more pythonic way? Seems a bit of a hack to be compare with the request, but I cant see any other solution?

```
@hooks.register("before_edit_page")
def before_edit_page(request, page_object):
    if isinstance(page_object, EventDetail):
        if request.POST:
            original = EventDetail.objects.get(pk=page_object.pk)
            if (
                page_object.live == True
                and request.POST["start_date"]
                and datetime.datetime.strptime(
                    request.POST["start_date"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
                )
                != original.start_date
                and page_object.messages.filter(sent=False).count() > 0
            ):
                messages.add_message(
                    request,
                    messages.WARNING,
                    _(
                        "You have changed the start time of an event that has unsent messages. Please review the timing of the messages."
                    ),
                )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than doing this in the model's `save` method, define an [`after_edit_page`](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/hooks.html#after-edit-page) hook function. This is called after the page has been edited through the Wagtail admin, and gives you access to the page object and the request.